# ID de tabelas fora de ordem

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela com 9 registros, as minhas identidades estão em ordem de 1 a 9, quando eu insiro um novo registro na tabela automáticamente um novo ID é setado, mas ele é setado com o valor 30 invés de com o próximo número que nesse caso seria 10 ( tenho 9 registros). Se por acaso eu vou inserindo registros o ID deles passa a seguir a ordem é ficam 31, 32, 33...

Não sei como faço para arrumar esse problema.

Comment: Bom você tinha inserido alguns dados e depois removeu eles certo ?

Comment: Sim...eu inseri alguns dados e depois deletei...

Comment: Então mestre respondido conforme sua necessidade veja se lhe ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando o comando abaixo você estará resetando o autoincrement chegando no que você precisa:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (minhaTabela, RESEED, 10)
```

Ou ainda para garantir que não terá falhas:

```
declare @max int;  
select @max = max(key) from minhaTabela;  
dbcc checkident(minhaTabela,reseed,@max)
```

Comment: Perfeito...obrigado! Funcionou!